# Force rebuild from within makefile

Tags: makefile, build, gnu, rebuild

Is there a way to force a complete rebuild (eg `-B`) from within a makefile?

I have added a pre-build step that increments a build number, stored in a text file, that is used by my project. The build number is only incremented if `newbuild=1` is passed as an argument to 'make'.

```
    pre-build:
        # This option increments build number
        ifdef newbuild
        increment_build_number
        endif
```

If this code is called, I would like to force a complete rebuild so that nothing gets out of sync, and I don't have to type `-B` whenever `newbuild=1` is used. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The `-B` flag does not force a rebuild of all targets, it simply requires that all targets that are *considered* be rebuilt. That is, Make will not skip any target on the grounds that it is up to date. So if you `make -B foo` then Make will rebuild `foo` and all of its prerequisites, but will *not* rebuild the unrelated target `bar`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Not really. If I enter `make newbuild=1`, I want to have that interpreted as `make -B newbuild=1`. Sure, one could touch every source file, but is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. declare the text file with the build number as a prerequisite of the other targets,
2. use make conditionals to also declare it phony if `newbuild` is defined.

Demo where `build.txt` is the text file with the build number and `target` is one of the targets to rebuild when `newbuild` is defined:

```
# Makefile
BUILD   := build.txt
TARGETS := target

ifdef newbuild
.PHONY: $(BUILD)
endif

$(TARGETS): $(BUILD)
    touch $@

$(BUILD):
    @[ -f "$@" ] && build=$$(cat "$@") || build=0; \
    printf 'build '; \
    printf '%d\n' "$$((build+1))" | tee "$@"; \
```

```sh
$ make
build 1
touch target
$ make
make: 'target' is up to date.
$ make newbuild=1
build 2
touch target
```

Comment: This is the answer. All that was needed was to touch the source files that are affected when the build number updates. Thanks to Beta and Renaud for your thoughts.

Comment: Hmm. I would not touch the source files. This looks like a dirty hack. If your source files do not change, there is not need to touch them. What would be much cleaner is to really express your dependencies. If this text file with the build number is used somewhere in your build process to build target(s), just add the text file itself in the list of prerequisites of the target(s). If it is not used your problem is a no-problem and you do not need to rebuild.